# Axios Interceptors Prevent Error logging into console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, refresh-token

Using interceptors for the first time to refresh an expired JSON Web Token. The response interceptor I implemented works successfully in refreshing the token every time, but still logs the error I throw at the server end from the jwt.verify. (I see 403 forbidden each time before token refreshes).

If I'm doing it correctly on the server end and in the client end, should this error even be logging in the browser? I don't want this error to be logging into console. Now I'm thinking I have to refresh the token before it even expires and not even use interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

check the order of responses from the server. Judging by the description, you are not waiting for the generation of a new token. If in JS terms check `async/ await` sequence